# how to open row in edit mode in gridview

Tags: asp.net

how to make gridview ro visible false when i click on delete button because i am using static data and 
i want to open the row in gridview in edit mode when i click on edit button.
How to do this in c#

Answer (score 0):

Are the Delete button and edit button are embedded wit the gridview Row?? Or they are separated and selecting a checkbox embedded wit the gridview Row and do the editing and deleting thing??